# How to get previous selected TabItem Index from TabControl?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Following xaml code for your testing needs.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="350">
<DockPanel>
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl" DockPanel.Dock="top">
        <TabItem x:Name="TabItem1" Header="London">
            <Label Content="London" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="TabItem2" Header="Paris">
            <Label Content="Paris" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="TabItem3" Header="Tokyo">
            <Label Content="Tokyo" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="TabItem4" Header="Istanbul">
            <Label Content="Istanbul" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

How to get previous TabItem Index from TabControl and show in the MessageBox?

I need vb.net code running from code behind.

Comment: You  could handle the `SelectionChanged` event and get it from the `RemovedItems` of the event args.

Comment: Why RemovedItems?

Comment: Check out my answer, sry i am not that familiar with vb.net, but you should be able to convert it easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RemovedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.removeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) is an `IList` property in the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` that holds the items that were unselected since the last time the `SelectionChanged` event occurred.
You could check it each time the `SelectionChanged` of the `TabControl` event occurred:

```
private void TabControl_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var oldTabItem = e.RemovedItems[0] as TabItem;
        }
    }
```

**xaml:**

```
 <DockPanel>
        <TabControl x:Name="TabControl" DockPanel.Dock="top" SelectionChanged="TabControl_OnSelectionChanged" > ..
```